# How to get type of a specific location using google maps in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in Android...

I'm getting longitude and latitude of a given location but **is it possible to pass a longitude and latitude of a location to google places api and get type of the place?**

For example if I pass the latitude and longitude to Restaurent the api should return me the *restaurent*.

Comment: I dont think that you understood my question... i want type of a location that given location is a restaurent, bank, atm, etc on the basis pf latitude and longitude

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39814117/google-maps-apis-to-return-place-type-based-on-latitude-longitude